# invalid identifier : sum of multiple column in sql

Tags: sql, sum, column-alias

I'm trying to calculate multible columns in this query

```
     SELECT
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 1 END)     AS OPD,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 1 END)     AS IPD,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 3 THEN 1 END)     AS DC,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 4 THEN 1 END)     AS PROC,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 5 THEN 1 END)     AS SUR,
(OPD + IPD + PROC) as Total
    FROM REF_TB_APP_TRANSACTIONS A,
         REF_VW_VISIT_TYPE      B
        
   WHERE     A.REQ_VISIT_TYPE = B.ID
         AND A.TO_EST_CODE = 20068;
```

but I got this error PROC invalid identifier

Comment: Try putting PROC in square brackets like this [PROC] or use a different word  PROC may be a reserved word or a reserved abbreviation for PROCEDURE.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS you are using.  You cant sum columns that are aliased like that, you would have to use a sub select and do the sum from there.  If you verify your DBMS we can create query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the three `SUMS` in the `Total` column in the `SELECT` directly, since you're using the aliases of those columns.  You could just do your `Total` column with another `SUM CASE`.

```
SELECT
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 1 END)     AS OPD,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 1 END)     AS IPD,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 3 THEN 1 END)     AS DC,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 4 THEN 1 END)     AS [PROC],
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 5 THEN 1 END)     AS SUR,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID IN (1,2,4)THEN 1 END)     AS Total
FROM REF_TB_APP_TRANSACTIONS A,
        REF_VW_VISIT_TYPE      B
WHERE     A.REQ_VISIT_TYPE = B.ID
        AND A.TO_EST_CODE = 20068;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the DBMS you are using. You cant sum columns that are aliased like that, you would have to use a sub select and do the sum from there. If you verify your DBMS we can create query.

If MS SQL the below will work.  A couple things:

PROC is reserved word, so either change that or put brackets around it (I went for brackets).  Also it is preferred if you use JOINS vs. the way you had the queries.

```
SELECT OPD, IPD, DC, [PROC], SUR, (OPD + IPD + [PROC]) as Total
FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 1 END)     AS OPD,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 1 END)     AS IPD,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 3 THEN 1 END)     AS DC,
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 4 THEN 1 END)     AS [PROC],
    SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 5 THEN 1 END)     AS SUR
    FROM REF_TB_APP_TRANSACTIONS A
    INNER JOIN REF_VW_VISIT_TYPE B ON A.REQ_VISIT_TYPE = B.ID
    WHERE A.TO_EST_CODE = 20068
) SUB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference the aliased columns as part of the `select` because in the order of query execution, they don't exist yet.

You simply wrap your query so it becomes a `derived table` and then you can refer to them in an outer `select`, see:

```
select OPD, IPD, DC, [PROC], SUR, OPD + IPD + [PROC] as Total from (
    SELECT
        SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 1 END) AS OPD,
        SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 1 END) AS IPD,
        SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 3 THEN 1 END) AS DC,
        SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [PROC],
        SUM (CASE WHEN B.ID = 5 THEN 1 END) AS SUR
    FROM REF_TB_APP_TRANSACTIONS A
    join REF_VW_VISIT_TYPE B on B.ID=A.REQ_VISIT_TYPE
    where A.TO_EST_CODE = 20068
)x
```

Guessing because you have a semi-colon this is SQLServer, in which case you will need to use `[]` around the reserved word `PROC`

I've also properly `joined` your tables as it's not 1989 any more :-0